# How to define variable depend on condition in XCode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I want to define some variables depend on whether it is run on Iphone or Ipad application. So I wrote this code

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    #define ABC @"122"
    NSLog(@"Ipad");
} else {
    #define ABC @"123"
    NSLog(@"iphone ");
}
NSLog(@" %@", ABC);
```

But in both iphone and Ipad it show 123.

Comment: maybe you cant define but another way is to use NSString or int or other variable and setvalues init.

Comment: @cat See the answer from @sch below. You need to learn and understand what `#define` is used for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this out:

```
#define ABC (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad ? @"122" : @"123")
```

This should work fine for you.

Comment: It may work, but there's no need for it. Far better to learn how #define is used and what it is for.

Answer (score 3):

`#define` tells the preprocessor to modify every occurrence of `ABC` in the source code by the value associated with it.

`ABC` will be substituted with `@"122"` in all the lines that follow the line `#define ABC @"122"` and by `@"123"` in all the lines that follow the line `#define ABC @"123"`.

This step happens at build time and not runtime. So you should define `ABC` as a string and set its value as follows:

```
NSString *ABC;
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    ABC = @"122";
    NSLog(@"Ipad");
} else {
    ABC = @"123";
    NSLog(@"iphone ");
}
NSLog(@"%@", ABC);
```

Comment: But incase I wanted to set some static varible in pch file, how can I do this?